# What to look for in vector time series, and how

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, references

In univariate time series, it's pretty intuitive to look for transformations to give you a stationary covariance noise component, e.g., linear or seasonal trends.  And you can look at the autocorrelation function and partial autocorrelation to get a rough idea of the ARMA order.  I have very little experience in it, but I know what I have to play around with in order to become familiar with it.

Now vector time series.  It's not so clear.  All the time series are potentially coupled to varying degrees.  I am concerned that detrending one series will yield misleading relationships between time series and/or hide relationships between time series.  Is there a good reference (online and/or hard copy) that describes the things to look for?  I have a doctoral in electrical engineering, so I am not that deep in the math.  Something geared for practitioners would be ideal, though with justification (math with intuition).

In case it makes a difference, I am using Matlab's Econometrics toolbox.  I went through the VAR/vgx tutorials (with varying degrees of appreciation for the math).  I'm a bit concerned about the lack of support for the MA part of VARMA parameter estimation, but not overly.  A colleague explained that you potentially lose intuition in the model if you have to convert VARMA to VAR.  I've dabbled in R, but it's hard to satisfy all package depedencies from behind a firewall.